# How to modify HTML file with Perl: preserving lists and erasing all other tags

Tags: html, perl

I would need to preserve couple of html tags in html file, but erase all the others.

The logic of the script would be:

```
- if there is <li> or <ul> on the line, do nothing (=write same line to output)
- otherwise if there is html tag, remove it (=just write the content)
```

Could someone please help me, this goes over my very limited perl skills.

Comment: Not trying to be annoying... but your need to show us something you've tried even if it is over your perl skills.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [HTML::Restrict](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aRestrict)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::Restrict;

my $hr = HTML::Restrict->new( rules => { li => [], ul => [] } );

my $html
    = q[<body><b>hello</b> <img src="pic.jpg" alt="me" id="test" /><ul><li>one</li></ul></body>];
my $processed = $hr->process( $html );

print $processed;
```

The resulting output is:

```
hello <ul><li>one</li></ul>
```